# Preventing a step back in python for rhino

Tags: python, function

Im trying to make a stepping function in python for rhino,
The function is supposed to make a step in a random direction, without going backwards.
How do i prevent a step back?

```
import rhinoscriptsyntax as rs
import random as r
r.seed(seed)



class Walker:

def __init__(self):
    self.x = 0
    self.y = 0


def point(self):
    shape = rs.AddPoint(self.x, self.y, 0)
    return shape

def step(self):
    choice = r.randint(0,3)
        choice = r.randint(1,3)
    if (choice == 0):
        self.x = self.x + r.choice(uList)
    elif (choice == 1):
        self.x = self.x - r.choice(uList)
    elif (choice == 2):
        self.y = self.y + r.choice(uList)
    else:
        self.y = self.y - r.choice(uList)

uList = [8,11,14]

w = Walker()


pList = []
for t in range(time):
w.step()
pList.append(w.point())

for t-1 in range(time):

a = pList
```

Comment: what do you call backwards? the `x`-direction? if so: only ever add (positive) numbers to `self.x`.

Answer (score 0):

This line:

```
choice = r.randint(0,3)
```

chooses one of 4 directions randomly. But if you don't want to go backwards, then you only want forward, left and right. So change the parameters to `randint()` so that it only chooses from 3 possible numbers, avoiding the one that corresponds to the direction you are calling *backwards*, whichever that is.